# Spring annotation based configuration not found with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: spring, maven, junit

I have some JUnit (4.10) tests configure using Spring (3.1.3) like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestConfig.class)
public class MyTest {...}
```

These run fine from within Eclipse, but with Maven (surefire) from the command-line it fails to find the TestConfig class. I used to have the same configuration using xml based configuration and that worked fine in both cases. I have verified that TestConfig.class is in the expected location in test-classes. I also tried to move it to classes in case the context loader didn't look in test-classes, but no luck. Any ideas?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/test/TestConfig.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.findAllAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:282)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:225)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:148)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:134)
```

#### Update

I had `<forkMode>never</forkMode>` for the maven-surefire-plugin.
Setting `<forkMode>once</forkMode>` (default) made the problem go away.

Comment: Troubleshooting this might require your project structure blueprint.

Comment: Which package/src tree is the actual test, MyTest in? Make sure it is in src/test/java. I have often put the test in the wrong location!